# How would I allow users to pay each other on Shopify?

Tags: html, paypal, shopify

The website I want to create needs to allow users to post an item they want to sell and have other users buy/pay for the item. Shopify only has options for setting up your own bank account from what I can see. I just don't want to get in over my head so Specifically I would like to know if Shopify allows users to pay other users rather than it going directly to my bank account, and if not how difficult would the code be to enable that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the multi vendor app on Shopify. Problem solved :)